# Calculating the pivot angle to rotate an object 90 degrees on both the X and Y axis with an angled 1DOF movement

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I need to rotate a rectangle (rectangle 1) that is parallel to another rectangle (rectangle 2). In doing so I need to change the orientation 90 degrees of rectangle 1 so it is perpendicular to rectangle 2 (so moved 90 degrees on the X axis) but also 90 rotated (on Y). I am constrained to a 1 DOF movement so it is going to be a pivot point that is angled on its X and Y axis. I've seen it done before just not sure how.

I can get close in random movements in cad but always off a few degrees.

How do you calculate the angle in X and Y axis the pivot point or rotation point needs to be?

See photos for clarity. Really appreciate the help!

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pythagoras is the answer. You have two equal rotations, so you need 90 degrees*sqrt(2) rotation about an axis with an angle of 45 degrees. However, for less obvious cases you get into a minefield of specifying what you mean. This is helpful, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: Let me see if I understand your problem; an object needs to be rotated about a single unknown axis; the single rotation needs to be equivalent to two successive rotations; one about X axis and another about Y axis?

Comment: Can you add two more figures, one after the first rotation about X axis showing the axis also and another figure after the second rotation about the Y axis with the Y axis clearly marked. Both figures preferably from the same point of view used in  second figure in the question.